# In a web application I used many console.logs for printing information on console. I want the timestamp of each console.log

Tags: javascript

I have a web application in which I have used many `console.log`s that are printing required information on console. I want the timestamp of each `console.log` to identify which `console.log` called exactly when. Is there is any general method by which we can do it?

For this should I go manually in and add the time stamp in each `console.log` or there is any method by which we can do it?

Answer (score 1):

On Chrome, there's a setting that allows you to do it.

If you want to do it via JavaScript, there's a nice implementation:

```
console.log2 = console.log.bind(console);

console.log = function(...msg) {
    const stamp = `[${Date.now()} ]`;
    this.log2(stamp, ...msg);
};
```

Comment: `console.log('where ', 'are', 'my', 'other', 'arguments')`? (+ you got a typo `.)

Comment: When I run it says 'Cannot read property 'log' of undefined', Any idea?

Comment: Fixed now @Kaiido.

Comment: You still have the typo `.

Comment: I've fixed the `.`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Date`?

```js
let i = 0;

setInterval(() => console.log(Date(), `=> message ${++i}`), 1000);
```

or write a wrapper as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56555427/6243352) suggests. I'd prefer not to redefine `console.log` in favor of:

```js
const log = (...msgs) => console.log(Date(), ...msgs);

log("hey!");
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is appending `new Date()` to `console.log` like,

```
console.log("You console message. Timestamp = ",new Date());
```